# DFA: Why is the transition function not a set?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

The DFA is a 5-tuple ($Q,\sum, \delta, q_0, F$)
where

-finite set of states ($Q$)
-finite set of symbols called the alphabet ($\sum$)
-a transition function ($\delta: Q \times \sum \rightarrow Q$)
-an initial or start state ($q_0 \in Q$)
-a set of accept states ($F \subset Q$)

Since in practice (programmatic implementation) the transition "production" (that is, $\delta(q_{from}, input) = q_{to}$) cannot be the same for all in $Q\times \sum$ and $Q$, then why is it not defined as "a set of transitions".

Comment: Downvoters, please comment on how the question can be improved. (If you don't think it *can* be made suitable, you should have voted to close.)

Comment: You should explain the "cannot be the same ...". I read it now 10 times and it still sounds like "1 cannot be equal to 2 so the moon is made of cheese". Sorry :-(

Comment: @Harald The function that maps from $q_{from}$ to $q_{to}$ cannot necessarily be the same function for all members of those sets, because e.g. the distances between the set members differ. Thus a single function definition cannot tell what to do with the inputs. So we are looking at $\{\delta\}$ rather than $\delta$. It's a small ambiguity in terminology, where the user seems to imply that piece-wise functions $\subset$ **function**s. Even when piece-wise functions are "more plural" constructs in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function *is* a set -- a set with additional structure.  A function $f: X \to Y$ can be thought of as a subset of $X \times Y$, i.e., as a set $S$ of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $f(x)=y$.  However, it's not just any old set.  To qualify as a function, it has to have the additional property that $f(x)$ has a single value.  Put another way, the set $S$ cannot contain two elements $(x,y)$, $(x,y')$ such that $y \ne y'$: a *function* is a set $S$ where that never happens.

The same applies here.  The transition function *is* a set (a subset of $Q \times \Sigma \times Q$), but a set with some additional properties/restrictions that must hold for this to qualify as a DFA.

So, it's defined as a function to emphasize the additional requirement that for each state $q$ and each symbol $s$, there is a *single* state $q'$ that you go to, i.e., a *single* transition out of $q$ on symbol $s$.

If there were multiple possible states you could go to, from $q$ when receiving symbol $s$, then it wouldn't be a *deterministic* finite automaton --  it'd be a non-deterministic finite automaton.

Comment: Again... You were faster and provided better answer. Cheers. There is nothing more to do than cleanup.